# Get the first row value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="tawktouser" rows="4" class="form-control"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="add" class="btn green">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
      var tawktouser = $("#tawktouser").val();
      alert(tawktouser)
    });
  });
</script>
```

I can't get the value of textarea in row manner - for example first row is name 2nd email 3rd is phone number - like this
Name : name
Email : abc@gmail.com 
Phone : 11111

Comment: You can split by `\n` but i don't think it's a good structure, you better have separate input box for each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  var tawktouser = $("#tawktouser").val().split('\n');
  alert(tawktouser[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea id="tawktouser" rows="4" class="form-control">
name
abc@gmail.com
11111
  </textarea>
  <button type="button" id="add" class="btn green">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
      var tawktouser = $("#tawktouser").val().split('\n');
      alert(tawktouser[0])
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: and how to get the column value by using this method?

Comment: what do you mean by 'column'?

Comment: Kamil Kiełczewski .. i just want to get only your first name "Kamil"

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#add").click(function () {
                var tawktouser = $("#tawktouser").val().split('\n');
                var i = 0;
                for(i=0;i<tawktouser.length;i++)
                {
                    alert(tawktouser[i][0]);
//                    var split_str = tawktouser[i].split(':');
//                    alert(split_str);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: If you have string `let s="John Smith"` then to get first word use `s.split(' ')[0]` to get second word use `s.split(' ')[1]`